# How can I prevent getting an exeption when canceling an already canceled Timer(because some times it's already canceled/done with it)? 

Tags: java, exception, timer

I tried to cancel a Timer.schedule() when I start a new one. Because I need 1 sechedule at once. But I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
```

As you can see the Timer is already canceled, how can I prevent that? 
I tried this code, still didn't work check it please:

Note: Everything in this code works fine except the 2nd line

```
Public void startTimer(byte h, byte m) {
    timer.cancel();//cancel the Timer whenever I start a new one
    Date d = new Date();
    d.setHours(h);
    d.setMinutes(m);
    d.setSeconds(0);
    UserInterface.setAlarmTime(h, m);
    timer.schedule(new Alarm(), d);
```

If I remove the 2nd line this code will give me a Timer but I doesn't cancel the old Timer so whenver I call this method I get more timers. And this is not what I really need.

So how can I prevent this Exception?  There's no methods in the Timer class that will tell me if there's a Timer in schedule, already checked it. So please help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
try
{
    timer.cancel();
}

catch (IllegalStateException e)
{
    // Log error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, because you can't call [schedule()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29) on a cancelled timer. If you're going to cancel the existing timer, you'll need to create a new one before you can schedule another task:

```
public void startTimer(byte h, byte m) {
    timer.cancel();
    timer = new Timer();
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is happening because you are cancelling the timer and then scheduling it again.

If you look at the Timer.java source code, here are two interesting methods --

```
 public void cancel() {
    synchronized(queue) {
          thread.newTasksMayBeScheduled = false;
        queue.clear();
        queue.notify();  // In case queue was already empty.
      }
}
```

And then the sched method --

```
 synchronized(queue) {
          if (!thread.newTasksMayBeScheduled)
              throw new IllegalStateException("Timer already cancelled.");
```

You should modify your code to not use the same Timer object to cancel and then schedule.. instead create a new Timer.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Timer.java.html

Answer (score 0):

Just cancel the timer.  Instantiate a new one and schedule it.

```
timer.cancel();
timer = new Timer();
Date d = ... // set the date
timer.schedule (new Alarm(d));
```

That said, your method name implies something different that what you are doing, which is really a `setSchedule`.

Answer (score -2):

Or other idea is to have global variable which is boolean. So first time you have set up the timer, the value becomes TRUE

```
if wasTimerSetup
 {
   timer.cancel();
 }
```